# How to use Code First generated context class with WCF DataServices?

Tags: entity-framework-4

How to use Code First generated context class with WCF DataServices?

I could use POCO template generated context class inherited from ObjectContext in conjunction with WCF DataServices with following configurations in WCF Service :

```
public class WcfDataService : DataService< NorthwindEntities >
    {
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        }

        protected override NorthwindEntities CreateDataSource()
        {
            var ctx = new NorthwindEntities();
            ctx.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return ctx;
        }
    }
```

However, context class which CTP5 generated is not possible in that same way because it does not inherit from ObjectContext, instead it inherits from DbContext.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by accessing the ObjectContext through the IObjectContextAdapter interface.

```
protected override NorthwindEntities CreateDataSource()
{
    var ctx = new NorthwindEntities();
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext
         .ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    return ctx;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ckal, but it is not working. I found solution here http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/12/08/entity-framework-feature-ctp5-released.aspx    However, it is still not a ultimate way to solve this issue and I realized that it needs some workaround from WCF Data Services team as above blog mentioned